# Remove underline on focus from :before element

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I'm not able to remove the underline from the **:before** element.

As you can see from the image, I set the underline of the link during the focus event, but I'd like to have the only text underlined and not the icon.

[image]

This is the code for the icon:

```
a:before  {
    content: "\f058";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

This is the code for the focus effect:

```
a:focus{    
    text-decoration:underline;  
}
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
a:before:focus  {
   text-decoration:none;    
}
```

Comment: display:inline-block to the before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `span` inside the link and apply `text-decoration: underline` on the inner element

```css
a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
}


a span {
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-left: .5em;
}

a::before  {
    content: "\f058";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Lorem ipsum</span></a>
```

if you cannot change the markup then you have to fake this behaviour, e.g. using a border with a pseudoelement

```css
a { 
   text-decoration: none;
   position: relative;
}

a::before  {
    content: "\f058";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    width: 2ch;
    display: inline-block;
} 

a::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid currentColor;
    left: 2ch;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

a:focus::after {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if was possibile to combine :before and :focus without editing the HTML code. Anyway, I'll follow your advice.
Saluti da Roma.

Comment: Hold my beer and wait 5 minutes

Comment: @Matt, look at my second snippet

Answer (score -1):

Text-decoration when applied on a link "a", will result in the underlining on the icon too. Instead, you can use : The Unarticulated Annotation (Underline) element in your HTML code.

HTML code:

```
<a href="https..//.."><u>Lorem Ipsum</u></a>
```

and then, style the  in CSS:

```
u{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```